# Как подружить composer autoload с моим autoloader'ом

Tags: php, composer, autoload

У меня есть такая структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В core.php у меня есть такой автозагрузка классов

```html
<?php
    // auto load classes
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
        include './classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
    });
```

А мне нужно использовать библиотеку Ratchet. Те нужно подключить файл `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`
НО если его подключить, то он конфликтует с моим загрузчиком

Comment: Перестать пользоватьяс своим автолоадером, а в своих файлах обозначить namespaces в соответствии с PSR-4, например. Ну и в composer.json сделать соответствующую запись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правилом хорошего тона является включение в composer загрузка и собственных классов проекта. Composer поддерживает несколько стандартов именования (и расположения) файлов, но самый продвинутый - это [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) ([другие](https://www.webmancer.org/all-about-psr-4/)).
Для подключения своих классов в файле **composer.json** необходимо сделать секцию [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) (пример ниже)

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "PAMI\\": "src/marcelog/PAMI"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "src/sibvision"
    ]
},
```

Для включения классов в загрузку достаточно выполнить команду `composer dumpautoload`

Пример пути:
У нас есть файл-класс **src/MyProject/MyClass.php** (начала пути идёт от каталога с файлом composer.json) c cодержимым:

```
namespace MyProject;

class MyClass
{
    ...
}
```

Значит в автозагрузке пишем `"MyProject\\": "src/MyProject"`
В своём коде вы будете писать `new \MyProject\MyClass();` или с использование `use`

```
use MyProject\MyClass;

new MyClass();
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, можете ли вы разъяснить? Мне нужно удалить мой загрузчик, потом записать секцию, но я не пойму, какие пути указывать (объясните, пожалуйста), а потом написать composer dumpautoload

Comment: @ВладРогов вам нужно удалить ваш загрузчик, записать секцию, выполнить команду. Обновил сообщение